# Installing icingaweb2 / icingacli under Oracle Linux 6

Tags: software-installation, php, oracle-linux, icinga2

I'm trying to install icingaweb2 / icingacli on a vServer running Oracle Linux 6. I've managed to install icinga2 from the icinga repo and php7.0 from the  ol6_developer repo. But if I try to install icingacli I get:

```
Error: Package: icingacli-2.6.1-1.el6.icinga.noarch (icinga-stable-release)
       Requires: rh-php70-php-cli >= 5.6.0

Error: Package: php-Icinga-2.6.1-1.el6.icinga.noarch (icinga-stable-release)
       Requires: rh-php70-php-pdo
.
.
.
```

The missing packages are installed just with other names:

```
# yum info php-cli
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
Installed Packages
Name        : php-cli
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 7.0.31
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to enable the software collection library from Oracle.
[rtfm ;-)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E59096/html/section_e3v_nbl_cr.html)

Comment: That's great. Can you please accept your own answer with the tick-mark next to the voting buttons on the left.